# Are my tattoos and other acts committed during a period of disbelief going to be forgiven?

Tags: sin, forgiveness

I was born a Muslim, became a disbeliever and repented back to Islam.  Are my tattoos and other acts going to be forgiven?

Answer (score 2):

Of course yes, Allah said in The Holy Quraan

> Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah . Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful (53) And return [in repentance] to your Lord and submit to Him before the punishment comes upon you; then you will not be helped (54) - [Surat Az-Zumar 39:53-54](http://muflihun.com/39/53-54)